# SQLite Table That Auto Increments Primary Key

Tags: c#, sqlite

**Well the main problem is that I get a error when trying to insert a Data Entry.**

(Not auto incrementing the primary key)

Table Creation:

```
SQLiteConnection _sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(_connectStr);
_sqliteCon.Open();

string query5 = "CREATE TABLE Merkmal(MerkmalID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ";
        query5 += "MerkmalName_FR TEXT);";
        SQLiteCommand command5 = new SQLiteCommand(query5, _sqliteCon);
        command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _sqliteCon.Close();
```

This appears to work fine.

Now for the Insert:
(***I Assume this is where my mistake is occuring***)

```
SQLiteConnection _sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(_connectStr);
_sqliteCon.Open();
SQLiteCommand insertSQL = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Merkmal(MerkmalID,MerkmalName_FR) VALUES (?,?)",_sqliteCon);
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("param1",null));
insertSQL.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("param2",SomeString));
insertSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
_sqliteCon.Close();
```

Some things worth noting:

1. I have attempted not putting a value at all. (With hardcoded values)
2. I get the not null exception error when trying to insert.

**What is the correct way to create or insert into a table so that it auto increments the Primary Key**

Thanks in Advance guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `MerkmalID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` to `MerkmalID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`

Most tables in SQLite have a `rowid` column (also aliased as `oid` and `_rowid_`). By declaring a column as an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (but NOT `INT`, `BIGINT`, etc., even though they refer to the same type), that column becomes an alias for the `rowid`.

When you insert a row omitting or a NULL `rowid`, SQLite picks a unique ID for you.

See also: [ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

Comment: Gonna give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a class which represents your db table and add the table in your db.

Create Table class

```
[Table("WordT")]
public class WordT
{

    private int _WId;
    [Column("WId")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [NotNull]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int WId
    {
        get { return _WId; }
        set
        {
            if (_WId != value)
            {
                _WId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Word;

    [Column("Word")]
    public string Word
    {
        get { return _Word; }
        set
        {
            if (_Word != value)
            {
                _Word = value;
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Add the table in your db

```
 SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(pth);
 var t = c.CreateTable<WordT>();
```

Comment: Interesting approach, will refer to this in the future!

Comment: Interesting! How will you make a non int or varchar column Primary Key so that we don't have duplicate value?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the INT keyword. Use INTEGER instead and it will work as expected.

So, correct code would be: `CREATE TABLE Merkmal(MerkmalID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NOT NULL ...`

Believe it or not it's different than just saying `INT` (I'm not quite sure why tbh).

Edit: I have tried this and I am able reproduce the problem, specifying INTEGER works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Check the [How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) in the SQLite FAQ. A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement. In your case you would define your PK column like:

```
MerkmalID INT PRIMARY KEY
```

and insert to it like:

```
INSERT INTO Merkmal VALUES (NULL,'SAMPLE MerkmalName')
```

Also you would preffer having referential integrity, included into your connection string:

```
string connectionString = 
    String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Foreign Keys=ON", dataDataAccessPath);
```

and `"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"` for every opened connection.

More details here: [Does SQLite support foreign keys?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q22) in the same FAQ mentioned above.

Comment: Inserting the way you suggest does not work. Just gets null values in the ID field. no autoincrement. Well I just referred to your article. And well yes, your answer is flawless. But still... not working.