# Where can I find the attributes "[Table("...")], [PrimaryKey], [AutoIncrement]"?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, attributes

I'm trying to implement this code for a SQLite table:

```
[Table("WordT")]
public class WordT
{

    private int _WId;
    [Column("WId")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [NotNull]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int WId
    {
        get { return _WId; }
        set
        {
            if (_WId != value)
            {
                _WId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

(Example is from here: [SQLite Table That Auto Increments Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28964177/1574221))

But I can't find the attributes in any namespace.

Where are they defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are defined in the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute?view=netframework-4.8)-namespace